# Spring Boot Inherit application.properties from dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have 5 Spring Boot Projects. All of them have a Maven dependency on a Spring Boot project No 6 with some shared/common classes. 5 independent projects have a lot of common properties assigned at each application.properties, which I'd like to abstract and move them to common project. Overall it looks like this:

```
                                            Project 1 (app.properties)
Common Project (app-common.properties) <--- Project 2 (app.properties)
                                            Project 3 (app.properties)...
```

Current problem is that app-common.properties is inside project1.jar/lib/common-project.jar and app-common.properties apparently do not load upon startup.

Is there a way to extend it from a dependency?

CommonProject Main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CommonApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected static void run(SpringApplication application, String[] args) {
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Project1 Main class looks like this:

```
public class Project1 extends CommonApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(new SpringApplication(Project1.class), args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really. 

I've ended up extracting all common values/properties to a java class with Constants, where values being @Inject 'ed  through setters. And that java class is used in underlying projects. Lame, but quick workaround. If I'll find a better way in the future, I'll post it here.

Comment: Thanks, so I actually tried what Anton has below and it worked. I have a common props files in a dependency and using the classpath props it looks to work great. Just put the annotation on where your declared your @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Thanks for you input! Based on your successful experience, I will accept Anton's answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233781/spring-boot-application-configuration-question do you have input for here?

Comment: How to use profiles in the dependency?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use PropertySource annotation and provide two sources for your app:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:app-common.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
    })
```

more details can be found there 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Since Java 8 you can omit parent @PropertySources annotation

Comment: Do you have input for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233781/spring-boot-application-configuration-question ?

Comment: How to use profiles in the dependency?

Answer (score 7):

Currently spring boot doesn't provide inheriting properties.

A spring boot application supports multiple property sources but the convention (read: built-in logic) for `xxx.properties` is to resolve the last `xxx.properties` if there are multiple properties files having the same file name.

There are many solution to this.

One possible solution is to

1. apply a custom profile to the dependency
2. include inheritable settings in the `application-customprofile.properties`
3. have the dependent(s) set `spring.profiles.include=customprofile` in `application[-{profile}].properties` (note: if set in `application.properties`, it applies for all profiles)

Another possible solution is to use a unique custom filename for the properties.

- i.e. instead of using the default `application.properties`, use `common.properties`

Comment: for example `java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files