# How to override spring boot starter's default properties in application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, kotlin

I created a multi module maven project that contains the `library` module (spring boot starter application) and `application` module (spring boot application that have included `library` as a dependency).

This is the structure of my project:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── kotlin
│       │   │   └── com
│       │   │       └── application
│       │   │           ├── ApplicationService.kt
│       │   │           └── Application.kt
│       │   └── resources
│       │       └── application.properties
│       └── test
│           └── kotlin
│               └── com
│                   └── application
│                       └── ApplicationServiceTest.kt
├── library
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── kotlin
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── application
│           │           ├── LibraryService.kt
│           │           └── Properties.kt
│           └── resources
│               ├── META-INF
│               │   └── spring.factories
│               └── config
│                   └── application.properties
└── pom.xml
```

**library/.../Properties.kt:**

```
@ConfigurationProperties("properties")
class Properties {
    lateinit var name: String
}
```

**library/.../LibraryService.kt:**

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Properties::class)
class LibraryService(private val properties: Properties) {
    fun name() = properties.name
}
```

**library/.../spring.factories:**

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.application.LibraryService
```

**library/.../config/application.properties:**

```
properties.name=library
```

**application/.../Application.kt**

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

**application/.../ApplicationService.kt**

```
@Service
class ApplicationService(private val libraryService: LibraryService) {
    fun call() = libraryService.name()
}
```

**application/.../application.properties**

```
properties.name=application
```

So, I have the `library` module where I put `application.properties` file with default parameter `properties.name=library`. The `library` module has `Property` class injected in `LibraryService`. `LibraryService` has the simple method `name()` that just returns value from property. I also have `application` module where I use `LibraryService` in `ApplicationService` and invoke `name()` function, but I have `application.properties` in `application` module where `properties.name=application`.

I expect that `application's` `properties.name=application` overrides `library's` `properties.name=library` and `ApplicationService::call` must return value `application` instead of default value `library` in `properties.name` in `library module`. But this does not happen. `ApplicationService::call` returns value `library`.

I created simple junit test to reproduce this behaviour (**ApplicationServiceTest.kt**):

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var applicationService: ApplicationService

    @Test
    fun test() {
        println(applicationService.call())
    }
}
```

It prints `library`. I would like to have the following behaviour: `library` has some several defined default properties, but I want to be able to override some of these properties in `application`. How to achieve that?

source code: https://github.com/grolegor/maven-multi-module-spring-starter

Comment: have you looked at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673216/spring-boot-multi-module-unable-to-read-properties-file-from-another-module

Answer (score 2):

Form the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

> **4.2.3.** Application Property Files
>   SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> **1**. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
>
> **2**. The current directory
>
> **3**. A classpath /config package
>
> **4**. The classpath root
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations **higher in the list override those defined in lower locations**).

So in your case `[library] config/application.properties` will be used, because it is higher-ordered then `[application] application.properties`.

Also, you cannot use `application.properties` twice.

Looking in your repository I would suggest that you remove the `/config/application.properties` from the library-module and provide default values in your `Properties`-class

```java
package com.application

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties

@ConfigurationProperties("properties")
class Properties {
    var name: String = "library"
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why so. Why does `library/.../config/application.properties` have a higher order than `application/.../application.properties`? `library` has added to `application` as a maven dependency. Thus, `library/.../config/application.properties` is in classpath /config package for `application`, right?

Comment: @grolegor the order of  loading properties has nothing to do with maven.

Comment: I tried to move the `library` application.properties under `resources`-folder, but it does not work for me, unfortunately, `library` does not see any properties in that case, it loads properties only if application.properties is in config directory.

Comment: I published the source code on github for convenience: https://github.com/grolegor/maven-multi-module-spring-starter

Comment: moved library/config/application.properties to resources (remember to rebuild with maven)

Comment: what am I doing wrong? I moved application.properties and delete `properties.name=application` from `application` module. so it must to load propertry from `library` application.properties, but it does not... I pushed it into my repository here - https://github.com/grolegor/maven-multi-module-spring-starter/tree/feature/properties-under-resources Can you check please? mvn test is failed

Comment: you are correct if you don't provide a value for `properties.name` the test will fail. edited my answer: hope it helps