# Spring Boot: Can't read "application.properties" in another Maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two Maven projects called "common" & "member". I put my MySQL connection config file(`application.properties`) in common project.

```java
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/train?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&characterEncoding=UTF8
spring.datasource.username=train
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**And I put "common" Maven dependency in "member" project, but when I started "member" project, it can't read `application.properties` in "common" project.** So it appears:

```
37.677 WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:592  restartedMain                    Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
37.684 INFO  o.a.c.core.StandardService    :173  restartedMain                    Stopping service [Tomcat]
37.726 INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger:82   restartedMain                    

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
37.780 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:40   restartedMain                    

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I'm sure something necessary have already add in "common" & "member":

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

So, how my "member" can't read the `application.properties` in "common"?

Comment: In your member project, do you have another application.properties?  Honestly I am not sure if Spring Boot is going to load application.properties from dependencies or is loading only from the application jar itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Inherit application.properties from dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663679/spring-boot-inherit-application-properties-from-dependency)